# How can I test for a nonexistant NBT tag?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have three villagers, which might or might not have a custom name.

The custom name is controlled by the `CustomName` NBT tag.

For villagers with a custom name, their `CustomName` tag looks like this:

```
{CustomName:'{"text":"Chad Ferguson"}'}
```

For villagers without a custom name, the `CustomName` tag is nonexistant.

Here is some code to test for if a villager has a certain name (using the `nbt` argument):

```
/execute if entity @e[type=villager,nbt={CustomName:'{"text":"Chad Ferguson"}'}] run tellraw @a {"text":"Chad is here!"}
```

Now I would like to test for an entity with a nonexistant `CustomName` tag, something like this:

```
/execute if entity @e[type=villager,nbt={CustomName:''}] run tellraw @a {"text":"An unknown villager is near"}
```

Now, this command won't work, because an *existing, empty string* is different from *the tag not existing*.

The `!` argument won't work, because of this:

```
execute
  if entity @e[type=villager,nbt=!{CustomName:''}]    # If there is an entity that does not have an empty custom name...
run tellraw @a {"text":"An unknown villager is near"} # then say a message.
```

That command will run if the tag is nonexistant *or* if the tag has something other than an empty string `''`.

How can I test for entities with a nonexistant NBT tag? I am in MCJE 1.16.2.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use this command:

```
execute
  as @e[type=villager]           # Tell all the villagers to run the following:
  store success score @s nbtTest # Store the success/failure of the final command to run here in a scoreboard.
run data get @s CustomName       # Get my custom name.
```

This will make all the villagers run the `/data` command to get their custom name.

And here's where the magic happens: the command *passes* if the tag exists, and *fails* if it doesn't. And since we're storing the success/failure in the scoreboard, we can just look: any entities with scoreboard value 0 have a nonexistant `CustomName` tag!