# What am I doing wrong to test for entities without an NBT tag set?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to target all entities that do not have their `SpawnX` NBT tag set, but I'm having trouble.

From [this question](https://www.reddit.com/r/MinecraftCommands/comments/euugbn) on Reddit, I've got this command so far, but this is causing syntax errors:

```
execute as @a[nbt=!{SpawnX}] run [command]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I test for a nonexistant NBT tag?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/374971/how-can-i-test-for-a-nonexistant-nbt-tag)

Comment: A problem is that it's possible for SpawnX to equal 0, and isung the answer you linked it would appear as if there is no SpawnX tag

Comment: @Oak10 As the author of that question and its respective answer, I can reaffirm that the linked question has a correct answer, although admittedly not the best. The best way would be to use `/execute unless data` instead of using scores and `/execute store`. I plan to update that question soon with the best info.

Comment: My bad, I read your answer wrong. An update would be great if you can :)